# How to use Route in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm learning from the Django rest framework + react tutorial. I have a problem, "App Component" is not showing up after entering the url address.

index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Route, Link, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom"
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const routing = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/app" component={App} />
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

function App() {
  return ( 
    <div>
      <h1>App component</h1>
    </div>
   );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Try `<Route path="/app" component={<App />} />`. See the [`Route` documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route).

Comment: It still doesn't work, and I tried to replace the word component with an element, but it doesn't work either. I'm at the beginning of my adventure with React and I don't understand much of the documentation.

Comment: Please check what version of `react-router-dom` you have installed. What you have in your question is the v5 components and syntax. From the project directory run `npm list react-router react-router-dom` and report back the version numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any overt issue in the shared code snippets.

## `react-router-dom` v5

The snippets you shared are the v5 components and syntax.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, Link, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const routing = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/app" component={App} />
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit how-to-use-route-in-react (react-router-dom v5)]

## `react-router-dom` v6

If you've somehow installed v6, then the `Switch` component was replaced by the `Routes` components, and now the `Routes` component ***must*** wrap any `Route` components. Another change is with the `Route` component API, there is no longer the `component` prop and `render` or `children` function props, all replaced by a single `element` prop that takes a `ReactElement`, or JSX, as a value.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, Link, Routes, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const routing = (
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/app" element={<App />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit how-to-use-route-in-react (react-router-dom v6)]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing your Routes parent component: Please wrap it like this and replace component with element as its not working with router v6:

```
import {Routes, Route, Link, Switch, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom"

const routing = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/app" element={<App />}></Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: 'Routes' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Comment: When i import this from react-router-dom it's still doesn't work

Comment: import is aswell

Comment: Sorry I skipped it. But when i import this it's still doesn't work

Comment: @kowalskijakub i edited my code

Answer (score -1):

Your `routing` is not a React component.
Try this.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Route, Link, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom"
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const Routing = () => (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/app" component={App} />
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Routing />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You need to pass React Component to ReactDOM.render(...), and
this is a React Component

```
const Routing = () => {
  return (...some jsx...)
}

# or short version
const Routing = () => (
  .... some jsx ....
)
```

This is not a React Component

```
const Routing = (
  ...some jsx...
)
```

Comment: Now it's Problem with:
Identifier 'App' has already been declared.

Comment: But when i rename the name of const and add it in render it's doesn't work when i get url http://localhost:3000/app